# Magento add approve state

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, sales

How to add Order **Approve** status Before **Processing** State. I try to add approve state. but after that processing state not changing when i change processing it's still showing approve only ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to add an extra state, what you can do is add a new status (pending approval) and assign it as a default for the state processing. Now any order that is invoiced will get tge approve status first, next you could add a button in the order view to approve the order, this then sets the order to processing.

Comment: sorry i can't get it

Comment: You can add a new status thru System->Configuration->Order Statuses. First add a new status: waiting_approval. Next assign the new status created to the processing state and use it as default. Now all orders that are invoiced will go to the status waiting_apporval (unless you specified something different with you payment extension). When you check the order you can change the status to processing (in the order view)

Comment: I tried in this way only but it's not working

Answer (score 1):

I believe this extension does what you're looking for. https://github.com/saderra/OrderApprover